# For Visual Studio Community 2017, 'Unreal Engine Installer' option is not available

Tags: unreal-4, visual-studio

On Visual Studio Community Installer, I cannot find 'Unreal Engine Installer' under 'Desktop Developemtn with C++' - 'Optional'. According to the tutorials I am learning, the 'Unreal Engine Installer' should be availbl.e

I have Visual Studio installed on 'C:' and Unreal installed on 'H:'; can this be the problem?

[image]

Comment: It might be helpful if you could add a link to the tutorial you're following.

Comment: It's from the tutorial "The Unreal Engine Developer Course - Learn C++ & Make Game" from Udemy. Unfortunately, the tutorial is not publicly available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this under `Mobile and Gaming -> Game Development With C++ -> Optional` in the current version of VS installer.
[image: Unreal Engine Installer]